# Embed all view controllers on navigation stack within other view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

That title might not make the world of sense so allow me to explain.

I have a view controller tha basically consists of two subviews, one of which I want to act as a sort of 'container view' for other view controllers. (Much like the container view object in storyboard.) The other subview will animate on and off screen causing the container subview to change size.

That's the easy part.

The hard part is creating a custom implementation of UINavigation controller, so that whenever a view controller is added to the navigation stack, it is intercepted, embedded in one of the above VCs, then that VC is added in it's place.

I don't know a huge amount about how navigation controllers handle the adding of view controllers which is why I am reaching out for advice.

I hope that kind of made sense, if not let me know and I will try my best to explain further.

Comment: You could create a subclass of nav vc and override the push method, but I don't recommend it.  I think you should rethink the two-subview vc, so that new instances of it can be configured with different contained vcs.  Use a vanilla nav vc, and, when it's time to push, create a new two-view vc, configure it with a particular contained vc, and do a regular push.

Comment: danh, This was what I was trying to go for, but I need something that I can essentially do once and forget about rather than having to repeat for every view controller.